# UITableViewCell losses repeated content in other cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've a UITableView which when a cell has the same content that other, this content only appear in the las cell drawed. My custom cell adds an UIView property to add dynamic subviews from other class.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"cell";

    CollectionCell *cell = (CollectionCell *)[tableView 
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[CollectionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] 
                autorelease];
    }

    [cell setCollectionView:/* Generated view in other class */];  

    return cell;
}
```

The concrete problem is:

My dynamic view is composed by, for example, 2 UILabels:

- if label 1 is a title, the title is unique for each row -> No problem, renders fine.
- if label 2 is a category, indexes from 0 to 5 have same category -> Only row at index 5 shows category label.

I can't create this labels in cell instantiation and add as subview because the cell content is all dynamic.

Thanks for your time and help.

**UPDATE:**

> I can't create this labels in cell instantiation and add as subview because the cell content is all dynamic.

I'm going to explain it in detail:

The content and UI controls added to collectionView property can be differentes each execution. In one execution collectionView could have an UIImageView and a UILabel, and next execution it has 2 UILabels (for example). This is why I can't create something like this

```
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[CollectionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] 
                autorelease];

        UILabel *foo = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:SomeFrame];
        [foo setTag:101];
        [cell.collectionView addSubview:foo];
    }

    UILabel *foo = [cell.collectionView subviewWithTag:101];
    [foo setTitle:@"This content is dynamic"];
```

Thanks!

**Update 2:**

Appears to be a problem with custom UILabel subclass. If I use original UILabel to show strings works fine.

Comment: "I can't create this labels in cell instantiation and add as subview because the cell content is all dynamic." please expand on this, and show what you ARE setting as the collection view. cellForRowAtIndex path _is_ the place to set dynamic content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to add subviews outside the block-

```
if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[CollectionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] 
                autorelease];
}
```

your subviews should only be added inside this block (the first time the ***reusable*** cell is created).

everything that happens outside (after) this 'if' block happens multiple times as you scroll your table up and down so that's where you edit the added subviews (only after the whole 'if block, outside it).

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895719/uitableview-multiple-sections-with-gui-elements-uibutton-uiswitch-etc/7896249#7896249)

Comment: Yes I know, but this is not valid for me because the added subview has differents UI controls and content in each execution or in differents cells and they are defined at runtime :(

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't work. Shows same behavior, I'm suspect that UITableView works fine and the problem is with the references to generated views... New content hides old content... I don't know.

Comment: is there a reason not to use [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:]; ? and just customize it then?

Comment: I don't understand the objective of use reloadRowsAtIndexPathds... It will draw the same as cellAtIndexPath, right?

Comment: the real problem is that a string which should be shown in 2 celds (independently of [super/sub]views) is only showed in last celd drawed. Same subviews and differents strings works fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4841/discussion-between-alon-amir-and-vbergae)

Comment: I will put this response as correct because this workflow is the correct way.